# How to share db from pc to pc on LAN

Tags: php, xampp, wampserver

can someone help me how to use xampp mysql database share from pc to pc...I have a php program and I'm going to use it in 7 computers but the database is installed only on the server pc...I want to share the database so that the other 7 computers can work and run the php program....how to do that? help please.

Comment: does the pc with the db have a static ip ?

Comment: Is the MySQL database listening on its private IP address?

Comment: yes...what should I do....so that the other pc run the php program using mysql db from server?

Comment: configure the pc's to use the ip of the db host and set the db on the host to alow the external access

Comment: Is your PHP code addressing the server by its IP?

Comment: How set the db on the host to allow the external access?? How to configure other pc to use the ip of the db host? I'm sorry I'm just a student still learning.

Comment: @Aram idk I think not..how to do that?

Comment: Offline you could not do that. I bet that you mean in Local Area Network LAN.

Comment: @user3179548 By writing something like `$mysqli = new mysqli('192.168.0.100', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');` in your PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using wampserver, follow these steps.
Go to C:\wamp\alias and edit the file phpmyadmin.conf

to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
 replace the lines

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

by

```
Order Allow,Deny 
Allow from all
```

---

Find the IP address using ipconfig
Then access database via http://your_machine_ip_addess_that_you_find_using_ipconfig.com/phpmyadmin/